# VSTO Adding control to chart

Tags: vsto

I would like to add a User Control to a Chart.

I can't use

```
ch.Shapes.AddFormControl
```

Because I would like to ad a User Control.

I'm using VS 2012 .NET 4.5 and Excell addin for 2013.

I have tried to use the following code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart ch = (Excel.Chart)wb.Sheets[1];
        ch.Activate();
        ch.Select();
        ch.ChartArea.Select();
        ch.Shapes.SelectAll();

        Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Excel.Range;
        worksheet.Controls.AddControl(new UserControl2(), selection, "fnis");
```

Ch is the Chart and I would like to insert UserControl2 on top of the Chart.

In the code above I get the error that selection is null.

Of course I have checked that all variables are not null and working etc.

Comment: Do you understand difference between Sheet Chart and Embedded Chart? First part of your code refers to Sheet Chart which you select/activate. In second part you trying to get Selection range object which is not available in Sheet Chart. Check you logic, try to improve you question and come back here...

Comment: Thank you for your comments @KazimierzJawor . The only function I can find that insert a control into a worksheet (or a chart sheet) is the AddControl. That function requires a selection. This is the reason why I need to select the Chart sheet

Comment: Basically, I need to find a function to insert a UserControl into a Chart Sheet. I have tried to use the AddControl but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and OP probably no longer needs an answer, but for posterity:

You could get around this by using the `ControlSite AddControl(Control control, double left, double top, double width, double height, string name);` overload to specify the chart location/size without worrying about selection.

If the selected area is important, you could first verify that it resolves to something and use the overload mentioned above as a fallback.